# Finitely generated abelian groups form an abelian subcategory of $\mathbb{Z}$-Mod

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories

According to Weibel's Homological Algebra book a subcategory $\mathcal{B}$ of an abelian category $\mathcal{A}$ is called an *abelian subcategory* if it is abelian and an exact sequence in $\mathcal{B}$ is also exact in $\mathcal{A}$. I get that that means that the kernels and cokernels in $\mathcal{B}$ are the same as in $\mathcal{A}$ but I don't understand a basic example - that finitely generated abelian groups form an abelian subcategory of $\mathbb{Z}$-Mod. Could you help me with the proof of this? Thanks.

Comment: The key input to the proof is the fact that a subgroup of a finitely generated abelian group is still finitely generated.

Comment: To verify that this is true you need to verify some conditions (namely, the axioms for an abelian category, then the additional hypothesis about exactness). Which condition are you having trouble verifying?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan the exactness part.